# Convert AU file to MP3

Tags: .net, audio, mp3

Is there any framework, technique or tool that I can use to convert an .AU file to a .MP3?

Comment: Does it need to be on the fly?

Comment: It has to be usable in a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend wrapping [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/), or executing it directly.  It can handle an extensive amount of formats.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Aumplib: C# Namespace And Classes For Audio Conversion](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8544/Aumplib-C-Namespace-And-Classes-For-Audio-Conversi)

> Aumplib (fully qualified name: Arbingersys.Audio.Aumplib) is a namespace of various classes that provide audio conversion capabilities, and can convert between many audio formats, including MP3.

Comment: I was trying to use these set of classes, but I cant find anywhere the com+ assemblies that he uses. That and he does not seem to be in the mood the help us finding them...

Comment: The framework is very concise. Too bad I wasn't able to use it